# SIM800L with helical antenna attached and reattached still doesn't pick up any signal

Tags: arduino, at-command, sim800

Three weeks ago I have bought a SIM800L module which had the helical antenna in the whole package. Mounted everything right triple checking always and also powering it from a Li-po battery (3.7 V 1200 mAh). Now, the module answers to my commands but it doesn't register into the network. For example if I write `AT+CSQ` it will return `+CSQ: 0,0` as for it doen't pick up any signal. Tried it with two different sim cards, one from Vodafone and the other one from Digi. I have also driven it around my area to see if it picks up any signal outside but no luck.

Comment: Now I have observed something else it blinks a few times stops completely then again blinks fast

Comment: Have you seen "Sim READY" in the terminal when module power on? Also if it has some power issues it would send "PWR Down" or something else in a terminal.

Comment: @M.R. now I have switched to an u.fl to sma antenna and same thing is happening. 9 blinks stops and then restarts

Comment: It says call ready, sms ready

Comment: Well I see something @M.R. very strange AT+COPS now returns the phone operators but AT+CSQ is 0

Comment: And also still restarting

Comment: AT+CBC returns this +CBC: 0,9,3478